# Add .active class when certain view is executed using hook_menu

Tags: routes

I have a view that is not related with a menu but I need to add .active class to an element of this menu when the view is shown. How can I alter the element adding a class active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Context module](https://drupal.org/project/context) for this. Context is capable of adding active classes to menu items based on conditions, e.g. path, content type, etc.

Comment: Thank you, the truth is I'm not familiarized with context module, can you please be a litter more specific on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Actually it was very simple, it solved my situation. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you already figured it out. You're welcome!

Comment: @yuki Can you also explain us what you did to resolve the situation in your case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is [`menu_tree_set_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7), and you also need [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) to figure out if to use it, eg:

```
function mymodule_base_init() {
  $item = menu_get_item();

  if ($item['page_callback'] == 'views_page') {
    if ($item['page_arguments'][0] == 'myview' && $item['page_arguments'][1] =='mydisplay) {
      menu_tree_set_path('menu-mymenu', 'some/arbitrary/path/in/the/menu');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the function menu_tree_set_path() available in versions prior to Drupal 7.9?

Comment: @yuki According to the API docs, it isn't.  However, as of 2013-03-25, the current version is 7.26.  There have been *a lot* of security related issues and bugfixes since Drupal 7.9 was release on 2011-10-26.