# How to make main navigation selector sticky?

Tags: routes, navigation

I have a page with a main menu and a sub navigation. Now, whenever I click on a menu point in my main menu, the text becomes bold (as long as the main page of the sub menu is selected ) but as soon as I hit a menu point in my sub navigation, the main menu selector (bold text in main menu) disappears. How can I make it sticky throughout all my pages within that certain menu point's sub navigation?

**edit 1**
Url: http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/

Comment: "menu point"? Did you mean menu item? Any item or some kind of item, like leaf item for example?

Comment: Is the hierarchical relationship between pages obvious from the URL structure. That is to say if a top level page's url is `/blog` will a child of that page have a url of `/blog/cerr`?

Comment: Nice Question, I would also like to know the answer for this one

Comment: Similar question + answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107896/add-active-class-when-certain-view-is-executed-using-hook-menu

Comment: @FelixEve no, the URLs are not that nicely broken down but the breadcrumbs for some reason can keep track of Main Menu -> Navigation properly. I added the url to my  original post under **edit 1**

Comment: @Mołot any menu item, see link above in **edit 1**, Thanks!

Comment: @Fahad if you're interested in an answer as well, you could up-vote my question...!

Comment: @cerr Your question was -1, I have already up-voted it, thats why its showing 0

Comment: @MF82 Trying to follow but can't (yet) posted an a question for further details to yuki

Comment: Can you elaborate on what part you need further explanation? E.g. what did you try with Context and what did or didn't work?